# Bounding the norm of Sobolev extension operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $\Omega$ is a sufficiently nice bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$, it's known that there exists a continuous linear operator $$\mathcal{E}:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$$ such that $\mathcal{E}(f)=f$ almost surely on $\Omega$. What do we know regarding explicit estimates of the operator norm of $\mathcal{E}$? As in, how does it depend on $p,d,$ the regularity of $\partial \Omega$, etc.

Comment: For a fixed open subset with Lipschitz boundary, the norm of the extension operator from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ depends only on $d$. As $\Omega$ varies, you should get dependence on its diameter and the Lipschitz constant on the boundary

Comment: Look at Thm. 9.7 in Brezis'  book *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Speces ...* and keep trak of the constants there.  This should not be too hard since the proof  is very well written.